# Google+ authentication with asp.net identity 2.0.0

Tags: asp.net, google-plus, asp.net-identity, google-openid, google-authentication

I want to implement the asp.net identity 2.0 with a project that I'm working with. This identity system enables logging in with third party login providers such as Facebook, Twitter, Google etc... However it seems that Google has closed registration to new OpenID 2.0 clients as of May 19, 2014. It's an attempt to force developers to use the new Google+ authentication system.

Any idea if the asp.net identity 2.0 system has been upgraded to use the new Google+ authentication system? Any tips would be appreciated.....

Thank you in advance

Comment: Seems like this questions would be better directed at the developers of asp.net identity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the article here on how you could update your app and the Google middleware for the new changes made for Google OAuth.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/07/02/changes-to-google-oauth-2-0-and-updates-in-google-middleware-for-3-0-0-rc-release.aspx

This is directly related to the Google middleware and does not affect Identity per say.